# how to fix replica set error

Tags: mongodb

I am getting this error

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "server is not running with --replSet" }
```

when I run the command on windows cmd

```
rs.initiate( { _id : "repl1", members: [ { _id : 0, host : "mongodb0.example.net:27017" } ] })
```

I changed it to

```
rs.initiate( { _id : "repl1", members: [ { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27017" } ] })
```

but still have same error

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, start your replica sets nodes with `--replSet xxx` (where xxx is your replica set name) -parameter. If you use config files, then `replication.replSetName: xxx`

Read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) how to configure/deploy replica set.